# Creating static variable snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am building a snippet, which generates fine, when I enter the `$name` that works fine, but when I press tab to go to `${2:description}` instead it goes to `$this`... My snippet is below, how can I bypass the `$this` and just go straight to description. Also is it possible to upper case any inputs a user inputs?

See here:

[image: https://gyazo.com/3022073092b13db8a62d9d828c811599]

```json
 "Get/Set": {
    "prefix": "-yadda",
    "body": [
        "/**",
        "*Getter for $name",
        "*",
        "* @return $name ${2:description}",
        "*/",
        "public function get$name() {",
        "    return $$this->$name;",
        "}",

        "/**",
        "*Setter for $name",
        "*",
        "* @param [$name] ${2:description}",
        "*/",
        "public function set$name($$name) {",
        "   $$this->$name = $$name",

        "   return $$this;",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Generate Getters and Setters"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you trying to escape `$` with `$$`, when `\$` would be the correct way to do it (this is documented [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar)).

This works for me:

```json
"Get/Set": {
    "prefix": "-yadda",
    "body": [
        "/**",
        "*Getter for $name",
        "*",
        "* @return $name ${2:description}",
        "*/",
        "public function get$name() {",
        "    return \\$this->$name;",
        "}",

        "/**",
        "*Setter for $name",
        "*",
        "* @param [$name] ${2:description}",
        "*/",
        "public function set$name($$name) {",
        "   \\$this->$name = $$name",

        "   return \\$this;",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Generate Getters and Setters"
}
```